# Linux program for viewing images like Irfanview that can open in a new window

Tags: linux, image-viewer, slideshow

I have Ubuntu 22.04. I'm trying to find a program like Irfanview on Windows that can open the thumbnails in one window, and the image slideshow in a separate window.

I tried installing Irfanview on Ubuntu using wine, but it can't see network drives, even if I mount them in the /mnt folder and every other program can see the files in there. I'm not sure why this is. Also, unlike in Windows, there doesn't appear to be an "open thumbnails with Irfanview" context menu option if I right-click on a folder.

Being able to open the slideshow in a separate window is extremely important for what I need it for. I tried Gwenview, xnviewmp, and gThumb, but none of them let me open in a separate window.

[image]
Here is a side-by-side screenshot. The window on the left is the Irfanview thumbnail view that has a folder browser to be able to find the folder & image. The window on the right is the main image viewer window. It has controls to scroll to the previous/next image, zoom in/out, etc. I'm looking for something like this.

Comment: so there is no confusion can you post an image of the type of program you'd like (layout)?

Comment: Sounds like you are aiming in a Multi-Monitor set-up, one monitor of viewing an overview with all the thumbnails and one monitor for viewing the currently selected image as full screen image.

Comment: @Robert Exactly! I use this for RPG gaming and I want to be able to have the thumbnails open on my laptop and the other window with the images on the main screen for the players to be able to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that XnViewMP has an option to pop out the Preview panel into a separate window. This isn't perfect, but it should work for my purposes as I can have the thumbnails in one window on one monitor and the image I want to show in a separate window on a different monitor.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [geeqie](https://github.com/BestImageViewer/geeqie), which has a lot of installation options (repos, flatpak, etc).

I am not sure about your "open thumbnails in new window" requirement,

Maybe it is the following feature: Type "L", or, via GUI:

- Click Toplevel Menuitem "View".
- Select "Float File List".
- The Preview Window will detach and reattach

Alternatively you might find help about that at the geeqie mailing list.

geeqie has so many features that I have never used, e.g. "Collections". Maybe some workaround for your requirement(s) is already available.

Answer (score 0):

There is some more such programms:

[XnView](https://linux.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Graphics/XnView-4612.shtml) is a utility for viewing and converting graphic files. XnView is provided as FREEWARE for private non-commercial or educational use (including non-profit organization). Image IPTC, EXIF metadata...

[Shotwell](https://pkgs.org/download/shotwell) is an open source photo organizer designed for the GNOME desktop environment. Features Import photos from folders or from any digital camera supported by gPhoto. Shotwell automatically...

[digiKam](https://www.digikam.org/download/) is an advanced digital photo management application for linux/KDE, which makes importing and organizing digital photos a "snap". The photos are organized in albums which can be sorted...

Comment: XNViewMP was the only one of these that could do what I was looking for (see my answer). I tried Shotwell and digiKam and neither of these were able to open the images in a separate window (at least in any way that I could find).